# REST Standards: Can the same Request Object used for POST & PUT requests?

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation, request

Say, these are the following POST & PUT Requests

```
@PostMapping(value = "/")
public ResponseEntity<CustomResponse<EntityExchange>> createEntity(@Valid @RequestBody EntityExchange entityExchange)
```

```
@PutMapping(value = "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<CustomResponse<EntityExchange>> updateEntity(@Valid @RequestBody EntityExchange entityExchange)
```

The above requests use the same Exchange Object but as for validation goes a field, say, "custom-field" can be empty in POST request while it should be present in PUT request. I can create two exchanges separately for POST and PUT, but is there a better way to reuse the exchange object but also have the field validations?

Note that I have used the "Exchange" terminology because both the request and response are of the same model.

Comment: Usually, through, `PUT`s are expected to happen at `/{id}/` - and you should decouple implementation constraints from your API design anyway...

Comment: @ernest_k Thanks for that, it was actually a mistake in the initial question, have edited now. The question that is bugging me is that, whether or not to use the same object on both the requests, if so how to have separate validations for each requests?

Comment: It seems to me that you find it natural to use the same representation... That's what I'd do too. As it seems that you validate before your method runs, it makes it a bit tricky (you could have set an ID field in the object before the PUT validation, or you could have set a flag in the object before validation to tweak the validation logic). In this case, what I'd do is just make the field *optional* then validate it manually in the `updateEntity` method (i.e., return a bad request by hand if the field is not set) - you would have to check that the ID points to an existing entity anyway.

Comment: I have followed a similar approach too, a manual validation method which will be called case-to-case. But the approach using validation groups posted by @user3487063 looks promising. Will be trying that too :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [validation groups](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/chapter-groups.html) for this purpose.

You need to have an interface first:

```
import javax.validation.groups.Default;

public interface ExchangeEntityPutValidation extends Default {}
```

You will use that in your DTO class like this:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class EntityExchange {

  @NotBlank(message = "...", groups = ExchangeEntityPutValidation.class)
  private String id;

  @NotNull private String other;
}
```

Next you can use this in your controller like below:

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@Validated
public class TestController {

  @PostMapping(value = "/")
  public ResponseEntity<CustomResponse<EntityExchange>> createEntity(
      @Valid @RequestBody EntityExchange entityExchange) {
    return null;
  }

  @PutMapping(value = "/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity<CustomResponse<EntityExchange>> updateEntity(
      @Validated({ExchangeEntityPutValidation.class}) @RequestBody EntityExchange entityExchange) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Basically, by this way you are asking Spring to apply ExchangeEntityPutValidation validation group to the validation step.

Comment: Cool, haven't heard about validation groups yet. Will definitely try this one out. BTW,  is the "HttpPostValidation" in the example referring to "ExchangeEntityPutValidation"